# Moving from Netgear ReadyNAS RN104 to a different manufacturer

Tags: networking, raid, nas, storage, readynas

my Netgear ReadyNAS RN104 has died, problem with the power and/or power supply, so I want to move the 4 drives set up in RAID 5 to another NAS. I want to move to a different manufacturer so what is the best way to do this. Bear in mind that the current NAS is now inaccessible but the drives should be all ok.
Can I just unplug the 4 drives and plug them into a new NAS?
If so what is the best way to do this, and am I restricted to certain types or manufacturers if I want to get a new model? I am unable to purchase a new Netgear NAS so I will have to opt for another manufacturer. Can the dives be accessed any other way to get a backup copy?
Thanks